# In MediaWiki, how can I include reminder text above the edit form when creating new pages?

Tags: mediawiki

In MediaWiki 1.22 I would like to add a section of reminder text directly above the toolbar when a user creates or edits a page.  There are several extensions that preload text directly into the edit form (such as [MultiBoilerplate](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMultiBoilerplate) or [NewArticleTemplate](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aNewArticleTemplate), but I would like to add text directly above the edit form's toolbar.

Would `$wgHooks[ 'EditPage::showEditForm:initial' ][]` and `$form->editFormPageTop` allow me to inject my text as described above?  Is there a way to avoid directly editing MediaWiki's EditPage.php file to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your warning to the page [[MediaWiki:Editpage-head-copy-warn]].

Comment: I actually used Help:Editnotice-0 as described in the [MediaWiki Help:Edit_notice entry](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Edit_notice) instead of using the Copyright warning section, but your answer helped. Thanks!